# Monitor inside core function

Tags: evaluation, core-language, monitoring

I like `DistanceMatrix`: its performance is surprisingly high, even for a big data.

However, for a huge arrays and custom `DistanceFunction` it still takes minutes for calculations, so it would be great to add a `Monitor` (with `ProgressBar` option) to it, but I have no any idea how to do it.

And this question applies to any functions that are not considered in the examples for `EvaluationMonitor`!

Comment: If you don't have access to the code for distancematrix, you probably can't effectively monitor its progress.